# SQL Query - Combine DISTINCT and TOP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

I have the following query I want to fire:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(5) fp.PostId FROM dbForumPosts fp
LEFT JOIN dbForumEntry fe ON fp.PostId = fe.PostId
Order by fe.Datemade DESC
```

However, when I fire it, I get the error:

```
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

I tried to change the query, so it used GROUP BY instead, but then I have the following problem:

```
Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column "dbForumEntry.Datemade" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

**WHAT DO I WANT:**

Think of this as a forum. There are posts (dbForumPosts) and entries (dbForumEntry). There are 0-many entries pr post.

What I want is to the get posts with the most recent activity (posts with the latest updated entries in).

Comment: Can there be more than one `Datemade` per `PostId`? If so which one to use for ordering purposes?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do, exactly? Are you trying to get the first five records and then get distinct values from them, or are you trying to get the distinct values, then only get the first five?

Comment: I added a text of what I want :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could find the most recent `Datemade` per `PostId` with `row_number`.  Then you can search for the most recent 5 posts:

```
select  top 5 PostId
from    (
        select  PostId
        ,       Datemade
        ,       row_number() over (partition by PostId
                    order by Datemade) as rn
        from    dbForumEntry
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Most recent row per PostId
order by
        Datemade desc
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same with a `group by` subquery:

```
select  top 5 PostId
from    (
        select  PostId
        ,       max(Datemade) as LastDate
        from    dbForumEntry
        group by
                PostId
        ) SubQueryAlias
order by
        LastDate desc
```

If `dbForumEntry` has an ID column (say `ForumEntryId`), a query like this might perform better.  The database can run this without compiling the `row_number` or `max(Datemade)` for the entire table.

```
select  top 5 PostId
from    dbForumPosts fp
where   not exists -- No later entry for the same post exists
        (
        select  *
        from    dbForumPosts fp2
        where   fp2.PostId = fp.PostId
                and fp2.ForumEntryId > fp.ForumEntryId
        )
order by
        Datemade desc
```