# TOP And DISTINCT in one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can i use top and distinct in one statement i am using this but not success . I dont know what i am doing wrong .

Below is my statement that i am using but giving me exception.

```
 SELECT  TOP 30 * from
 (            
  SELECT   DISTINCT       
  Bill.CLIENTID,Bill.TRANDATE,Bill.TRANTYPE,Bill.DUE,Bill.AMOUNT,Bill.paid,ORDE_.INVDATE ,Bill.TRANDESC,Bill.INVNUM     
  FROM BILLING Bill  LEFT OUTER JOIN  ORDE_  ON Orde_.INVNUM = Bill.INVNUM          
 WHERE  Bill.CLIENTID = 1047  )
```

Comment: may i know what is reason to down grad this question @viruss mca

Comment: @Abishek. Wasn't me, but I'm guessing it's because you haven't described the error.

Comment: @abhisek: i haven't down vote your question.

Comment: `try select distinct top 30....<rest of query>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query - Combine DISTINCT and TOP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219582/sql-query-combine-distinct-and-top)

Comment: You should be aware that error message is your first and best clue as to what is wrong. Always include it in a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Missing table alias for the subquery may be the cause of your error.  You don't need a subquery, you can use both `Distinct` and `Top` together.

`Top(n)` records depend on the order of the result set. So don't forget to explicitly Order your results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(30) Bill.CLIENTID,Bill.TRANDATE,Bill.TRANTYPE,Bill.DUE,Bill.AMOUNT,
                        Bill.paid,ORDE_.INVDATE ,Bill.TRANDESC,Bill.INVNUM     
FROM BILLING Bill  LEFT OUTER JOIN  ORDE_  ON Orde_.INVNUM = Bill.INVNUM          
WHERE  Bill.CLIENTID = 1047
ORDER BY ....
```

Answer (score 1):

It may help

```
SELECT  TOP 30 * from
 (            
  SELECT   DISTINCT       
  Bill.CLIENTID,Bill.TRANDATE,Bill.TRANTYPE,Bill.DUE,Bill.AMOUNT,Bill.paid,ORDE_.INVDATE ,Bill.TRANDESC,Bill.INVNUM     
  FROM BILLING Bill  LEFT OUTER JOIN  ORDE_  ON Orde_.INVNUM = Bill.INVNUM          
 WHERE  Bill.CLIENTID = 1047  ) Alias
```